# dynamically add 'td' and bindings using knockout.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Is there a way to dynamically add 'td with data-bind:"text: propertyName"' without explicitly writing the property name as below?:

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'Tmpl', foreach:person}">                      
</tbody>

<script id="Tmpl" type="text/html">
 <tr class="tableRow">
  <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
  <td data-bind="text: Age"></td>
 </tr>
</script>
</table>
```

My dataSource for 'person' can have different property names and a different number of td's so, its very dynamic. What I tried was:

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'Tmpl', foreach: person}">                      
</tbody>
<script id="assessmentTmpl" type="text/html">
 <tr class="tableRow">
  <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
 </tr>
</script>
</table>
```

But that only gives the object itself not the property. I am trying to do this by just using the knockout.js, but I may need to dynamically add td's with jquery instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, try custom binding!

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'Tmpl', foreach:person, as : per}">                      
    </tbody>

    <script id="Tmpl" type="text/html">
        <tr class="tableRow" data-bind="createRow: per">
        </tr>
    </script>
</table>

ko.bindingHandlers.createRow =
{
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        for(var item in valueAccessor())
        {
            $(element).append('<td data-bind="text:' + valueAccessor()[item] + '"></td>');
        });
    }
};
```

I think this will work, if it isn't data binding correctly, you can just output the value in that update method yourself:

```
$(element).append('<td>' + valueAccessor()[item] + '</td>');
```

Comment: Try this then, given an alias to each person (you should probably rename person to indicate that it contains multiple objects, then you can rename the alias to person).

Answer (score 0):

Using the same approach than the one suggested by the precedent answer, i came with the following code.
Please note that it could be refactorized to something more 'elegant'.

The view code :

```
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableRow" data-bind="createTheadRow: userEntityObj.UserList()[0]"></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:userEntityObj.UserList">
        <tr class="tableRow" data-bind="createTbodyRow: $data"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The custom bindings :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.createTheadRow =
{
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        if($(element).html() == '')
        if (valueAccessor() != null)
        for (var key in valueAccessor())
            $(element).prepend('<th>' + key + '</th>');
    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.createTbodyRow =
{
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        if (valueAccessor() != null)
        for (var key in valueAccessor())
            $(element).prepend('<td data-bind="text:' + key + '"></td>');
    }
};
```

With this, you can generate a table without knowing the properties of the source.
You can, also, add custom TD fields (for example for edit/delete button) just by adding this one in the tr block (the binding make prepend so your custom TD will appear in the end of the TR)