# How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object using data-bind Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the next model:

```
var simpleModel = function(){
    var self = this;   
    self.name = "Simple model";
    self.attributes = {  
        attr1: ko.observable("1"),
        attr2: ko.observable("2"),
        attr3: ko.observable("3")
    };
}
```

I would like to be able to enumerate the `attributes` property of this model and showing the key and the value like this:

```
<div>
   <span>attr1</span><span>1</span>
   <span>attr2</span><span>2</span>
   <span>attr3</span><spam>3</span>
</div>
```

I was trying to solve this based on the for loop behavior from javascript when it's used on an object, but failed:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: designAttributes, as: 'dAttr' }">
   <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
   <span data-bind="text: dAttr[$index]"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamically add 'td' and bindings using knockout.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209958/dynamically-add-td-and-bindings-using-knockout-js)

Comment: Yeah, thought I'd answered something similar recently! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that foreach is created for array only so you need function to convert your object to array. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wW2TE/2/)

```
window.objToArray = function (obj) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        result.push({ key: i, value: obj[i]});
    }
    return result;
};
```

and use them in binding:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: window.objToArray(items)">
```

Comment: Easy and elegant, but I like more the custom binding idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Custom binding:

```
<div data-bind="createSpan">

ko.bindingHandlers.createSpan =
{
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)
    {
        for(var item in valueAccessor())
        {
            $(element).append('<span data-bind="text:' + valueAccessor()[item] + '"></span>');
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: This wold be perfect if it could be more modular...like the foreach binding but for objects. I will try to see how the foreach binding works and transform it to objForeach :) Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed observable to get the structure you want and bind to that. I have taken the liberty of modifying your JS and making self.attributes an observable.

Here is the fiddle with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/A846H/

```
var simpleModel = function(){
var name = 'Simple model',
    attributes = ko.observable({
        attr1: ko.observable('1'),
        attr2: ko.observable('2'),
        attr3: ko.observable('3')
    }),
    splitAttributes = ko.computed(function(){
        var splitAttribs = [];
        for(var attr in attributes()){
            splitAttribs.push({
                name: attr,
                val: attributes()[attr]
            });
        }

        return splitAttribs;
    }),
    vm = function(){};

    vm.name = name;
    vm.attributes = splitAttributes;

    return vm;


}

ko.applyBindings(new simpleModel());
```

And here is the HTML binding for it.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: attributes">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span> = <span data-bind="text: val"></span> <br/>
</div>
```

Hope that is what you are looking for.

Cheers!
Suj